# Populate search view in android from text files

Tags: java, android

I am trying to populate search and listview from text file and am having issues with this code can someone please help me This is the error message in the log cat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at searchviewsqlite.MyActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu"
```

This is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Menu m;

    final Context context=this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        DatabaseTable db=new DatabaseTable(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

            SearchManager searchManager =(SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));//Error here

        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;

            default:

                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my menu code below

```
<item

    android:id="@+id/search"

    android:title="Search"

    android:icon="@drawable/search"

    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"

    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Comment: try to move setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreate.

Comment: post the xml code of your menu

Comment: Post your menu layout

Comment: this is your complete menu layout? there is a tag `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` that should wrap the `<item>` tags...